# Meaning of 不人気街道一直線

Tags: expressions, internet-slang

不人気街道一直線

I found this expression on few Japanese sites (social mostly, so it seems like some slang?), but what does it mean?　I guess it means 'unpopular', but that's not enough for me if I see so many other elements to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`～街道【かいどう】` is used metaphorically in the same way as "Road to (success, victory, becoming an actor, etc)". And `～街道【かいどう】一直線【いっちょくせん】` is a set phrase which means "marching down the road to ～".

不人気街道一直線 itself is not a set phrase, but a kind of ironical usage of this phrase. It roughly means "falling straight down to the abyss of unpopularity."

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was suspecting exactly something like that, just couldn't put it in mind.